# Usage of micrometer-registry-prometheus slow down my Spring Boot application

Tags: spring-boot, prometheus, micrometer, spring-micrometer, prometheus-java

I have Spring Boot application 2.5.7 where I set up a micrometer to scrape metrics
`runtimeOnly("io.micrometer:micrometer-registry-prometheus")`

When I make a request locally `http://localhost:8081/actuator/prometheus`
There are no performance problems with my application

But when I make a request to the actuator on the server with a high load
`https://myserver:8081/actuator/prometheus`
it returns a lot more data in response and it also slows down all request that is currently running on my server.
The problem appears even after one request to `/actuator/prometheus`

Is there any way to optimize the micrometer work(while returning the same ammount of metrics), so it will not slow down my application?

Answer (score 1):

Without sufficient data it is hard to give a recommendation. If the slowness is due to insufficient memory/garbage collection, try increasing the memory of your application.

Reviewing the metrics being returned may also give you some ideas, for example if you have a high thread count, I think there is a pause when Micrometer iterates over the thread statuses. You could look into disabling that metric.